# Making Functions Act Differently Depending on Input Case MATLAB

Tags: matlab, if-statement, for-loop, switch-statement, case

So I'm having trouble with my code (hence why I'm asking this question). My goal is to write a function, that has a different output depending on the case of the input. There were three different cases I had to worry about: double, logical and char. I've already dealt with the double case and that code is working perfectly fine. I'm having issues with the other two cases.

This is what I have to do for the logical case:  If the first input is logical class, then the 2nd input is guaranteed to represent a number and be length 1. However, the 2nd input can vary between double and char class. So it could either be [5] or '5', which are very different. For your first output in this case, simply output the opposite of the first input. For example, if your first
input was [true false false true], then your first output should be [false true true false]. For your second output in this case, check whether the number represented in the 2nd input is even, and output
a single true or false, true is the number is even. If the class of that input was double, then simply leave this second output as logical class. If the class of the 2nd input was char, then output a string of 'True' or 'False' instead of just a logical value.

Example:

```
  [out1, out2] = ifOnlyIfOnly(true, '22')
  out1 = false  %logical class
  out2 = 'True'  %as a string
```

I get false (as a 0) but my second output is '1 1'. I need it to be 'True'

For the char case: Char: If the first input is char class, then the second input is always   guaranteed to be another string. You will need to find which string is longer, and remove indices from it that go past the length of the shorter string. Your first output will then be the two strings
concatenated together with a space between them, and the second output will be a single true of false: true if the inputted strings were originally the same length, and false if they were not and you had to shorten one. If you have to shorten one of the inputted strings, then the shortened version of that string should be what you use to concatenate them together for your first output.

```
function[Output1, Output2] = ifOnlyIfOnly(input1, input2)

if isnumeric(input1) == 1
    Output1 = input1/sum(sum(input2));
    Output2 = input2 .* input1;
end
%Works perfectly here ^
if islogical(input1) == 1 && ischar(input2) == 1
    Output1 = ~input1;
%My Output1 works correctly
    Output2 = char((mod(input2, 2) == 0;
%I need to figure out how to convert from a logical case to a char case here.
%Should I do something along the lines of num2str here?
elseif islogical(input1) == 1 && isnumeric(input1) == 1
    Output1 = ~input1;
    Output2 = mod(input2, 2) == 1;
end
  if ischar(input1) == 1
    switch input1
        case strcmp(input1, input2) == 1
            Output1 = [input1 ' ' input2];
            Output2 = false;
    end
```

I cannot run my third testcase '[out1, out2] = ifOnlyIfOnly('Hello', 'Worldddd')' since it keeps flagging me for the isnumeric part up top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try if that works for you:

```
bool2char = @(x) getfield( {'false','true'}, {x+1});

if isnumeric(input1)
    Output1 = input1/sum(sum(input2));
    Output2 = input2 .* input1;
end

if islogical(input1) && ischar(input2)
    Output1 = ~input1;
    Output2 = bool2char( ~(mod(str2double(input2), 2)) );

elseif islogical(input1) && isnumeric(input2)
    Output1 = ~input1;
    Output2 = ~(mod(input2, 2));
end

if ischar(input1)
    n1 = numel(input1); n2 = numel(input2);
    n = min( [n1,n2] );
    Output1 = [input1(1:n) ' ' input2(1:n)];
    Output2 = ~( n1-n2 );
end
```

---

some remarks:

Constructs like

```
if islogical(input1) == 1 && ischar(input2) == 1
```

are pointless

```
if islogical(input1) && ischar(input2)
```

does the same.

The conversion from boolean to char can be done with that anonymous function:

```
bool2char = @(x) getfield( {'false','true'}, {x+1});
```

As you can see you can just do linear indexing with the boolean value, the conversion to double is done by `+`.

With `strcmp` you compare the content of strings, not their length. Use `numel` instead.

For the char case: Don't check which string is shorter, just shorten them anyway. If there is no shorter string, there is nothing to shorten. Good as well.

---

As you know from my previous answer, I don't like too much if-conditions. Alternatively you can use `switch` and `case` to make you code a little slimmer.

```
switch class(input1)
    case 'double'
        Output1 = input1/sum(sum(input2));
        Output2 = input2 .* input1;  
    case 'logical'
        if ischar(input2)
            Output1 = ~input1;
            Output2 = bool2char( ~(mod(str2double(input2), 2)) );
        else
            Output1 = ~input1;
            Output2 = ~(mod(input2, 2));
        end
    case 'char'
        n1 = numel(input1); n2 = numel(input2);
        n = min( [n1,n2] );
        Output1 = [input1(1:n) ' ' input2(1:n)];
        Output2 = ~( n1-n2 );
end
```

Comment: I've never actually learned the whole bool2char conversion, or numel technically, but I've seen numel before. I was going to try to use length instead, but all of what you'e done makes sense. And it works properly :) I appreciate it!

Comment: Well there is no real bool2char conversion. The function just provides a cell array with the two possible strings and getfield allows to access the cell within the same line.

Comment: Oh...we haven't learned about those either, but I'm at the point where I'm willing to use it if I can see how it works. Abstraction ftw. And the switch statements do make it look much prettier. Though I am still working on understanding them.